# How to apply pointer-events for only one underneath element

Tags: css, pointer-events

I have below code:

```
          <div className="my-div" />
              <button className="my-btn1">this button should be clickable</button>
              <button className="my-btn2">this button should not be clickable</button>
          </div>
```

The `position` of `.my-div` is `relative` and button's are `absolute`. If I set `pointer-events:none` for `.my-div`, both of buttons would be clickable, but I want `.my-btn1` be clickable and `.my-btn2` don't be clickable.

Comment: The HTML attribute [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) isn't sufficient? If not, why not set `pointer-events: none` for `my-btn2` instead of `my-div`?

Comment: No, they shouldn't be disabled. There is more elements.

Comment: If the buttons are positioned on top of each other, how do you expect the bottom button that isn't visible to be clicked?

Comment: buttons are in different positions, both of them are visible.

Comment: Again, why not set `pointer-events: none` for my-btn2 instead of my-div?

Comment: Because I have my-btn3, my-btn4, .... and I want to my-btn1 should be clickable and others not be clickable.

Comment: It would be helpful if you described your use case in more detail. Without understanding the use case, it is unlikely you'll get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Yes you're right, this code is simplified version of my use case I had a complicated one. anyway I resolved that in another way. @beerwin

Answer (score 1):

Declaring `pointer-events: auto` on `my-btn1` appears to allow it to be clickable

```css
.my-div {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.my-btn1 {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.my-btn2 {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-div">
  <button class="my-btn1">this button should be clickable</button>
  <button class="my-btn2">this button should not be clickable</button>
</div>
```